# Loading GIS data in a complex NetLogo model

Tags: gis, simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

This is a hunter-gatherer agent-based model I am attempting to integrate GIS layers in: https://auckland.figshare.com/articles/Source_Code_Netlogo_5_3_1_for_Perry_O_Sullivan_Hunter-gatherer_agent-based_model_see_Journal_of_Archaeological_Method_Theory_/5327944

I cannot figure out how to use my own data for agent interaction. This may be a bit to ask for here, but does anyone know by looking at this model's code in NetLogo 5.3.1 able to identify the most straightforward way to disable the landscape initialization the model is running without throwing anything else off and load my data in its place?

The model itself generates an abstract landscape using the SINMAP algorithm (included in the simmap_code_v1.8.nls). I am able to load my layers into the model with the following code

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ twelveK-dataset
          sinks-dataset
          elevation]

;; Landscape initialization based on GIS data.


to setup
  clear-all

  ;Load all datsets
  set twelveK-dataset gis:load-dataset "twelveK.asc"
  set sinks-dataset gis:load-dataset "Combined Karsts.shp"
  ; Set the world envelope to the union of all of our dataset's envelopes
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of twelveK-dataset)
                                                (gis:envelope-of sinks-dataset))
  reset-ticks
end


; Drawing a raster dataset to the NetLogo drawing layer, which sits
; on top of (and obscures) the patches.
to display-elevation
  gis:paint twelveK-dataset 52
end

; Drawing point data of karst features shapefile (combinded GIS layer of reported
; and modeled sinks in Gulf Of Mexico) and optionally loading the data into turles
to display-sinks
  gis:set-drawing-color blue
  gis:draw sinks-dataset 1
end
```

Ideally, the patches being interacted with would be buffers around my sinks-dataset. The model would work the same way but with a spatially-explicit setting, not the random one generated with the simmap_code_v1.8.nls package.